# Join three tables in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to join three tables in mysql. I have three tables called post, sharepost and user. I want to join sharepost and user to retrieve the first and last name of the user who shared the post and I want to join post and user to retrieve the first and last name of the original user of the post with other columns.

The post table has the following columns,

```
postID, title, description, userID, dateposted,likes.
```

The sharepost table has,

```
postid, shareuserid, dateshared,likes
```

The user table has,

```
userID, firstname, lastname, datejoined, email, password, birthdate.
```

postid in sharepost references postID from the post table.
The userID and shareuserid both refers to the same user table.
I want to retrieve the original user and the user who shared the post as well.

sample data for the post table are,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHIMw.png)

sample data for the sharepost table are,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZzSX.png)

sample data for the user table are,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hNXS.png)

The following query can retrieve the first and last name of the user who shared the post,

```
SELECT P.postID,P.userID, P.title, P.description, S.shareuserID,
U.firstname, S.dateShared, S.likes from sharepost S join post P 
on S.postID=P.postID join user U on S.shareuserID=U.userID
```

I expect to retrieve the original user from the post table and the user who shared the post from the sharepost table as well but I only get the name of the shared user.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ungye.png)

Comment: Sample data and expected results, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @BenM 's answer I managed to modify my query as the following which returned my expected results,

```
SELECT P.postID,
          P.userID, 
          P.title, 
          P.description, 
          S.shareuserID, 
          U.firstname AS sharer_name, 
          U1.firstname as author_name, 
          S.dateShared, S.likes 
     from sharepost S 
join post P on S.postID = P.postID 
     join user U on S.shareuserID = U.userID 
     join user U1 on P.userID=U1.userID
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
    SELECT p.postID,
           p.userID AS author_id,
           p.title,
           p.description,
           sp.shareuserid AS sharer_id,
           sp.dateShared,
           sp.likes,
           u1.firstname AS author_forename,
           u1.lastname AS author_surname,
           u2.firstname AS sharer_forename,
           u2.lastname AS sharer_surname
      FROM post p
INNER JOIN sharepost sp ON p.id = sp.postid
INNER JOIN user u1 ON p.userID = u1.userID
INNER JOIN user u2 ON sp.shareuserid = u1.userID
```

It's worth noting though that I can't see any reference to `likes` in your schemas. Not sure if that's a typo?

Comment: So whenever there is a need to join one table with two other tables we have to give unique aliases although its the same table?

Comment: When you're joining the same table on multiple fields, yes.

Comment: Why can't `join on` be used instead of `inner join on`? Is there a difference?

Comment: It does not return anything.

Comment: It can be. `JOIN ON` and `INNER JOIN ON` are the same.

Comment: No errors it just does not return anything. +I have enough data that should be returned.

Comment: You might have more luck if you put together an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Thank you but it seems kind of confusing. Do you mind to explain the purpose of SQL fiddle?